# Identify LEGO set with "5T33R" sticker

Tags: set-identification

Tiny orange truck with license plate "5T33R". Also has "Steer Well" sticker, flames on the sides. Have searched and can’t find online.

Answer (score 3):

That [stickered tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3069bpb180) seems to only appear in set [8186](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8186) from 2009.